# truffle migrate fails:Insufficient gas limit or exceed gas limit

Tags: truffle-migration

```
$ truffle migrate

Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\Voting.sol...
Writing artifacts to .\build\contracts
Using network 'development'.
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful 
transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

I am facing error during migration.

my truffle.js is:

```
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // Match any network id
      gas: 4712388,
      from: '0xe8321ca272cb292Cc2485fBa749Fd20d40ed5C44'
    }
  }
};
```

gas limit 4712388 then insufficient...

gas limit 4712389 then exceeds...what to do ?

Comment: is the account unlocked and has funds?

Comment: Yes account is funded with 4 ether and unlocked as well..

Comment: Please add your code for Voting.sol so I can try to reproduce the error and be more helpful. tks

Comment: I am following 
https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f